# Button Click in Coordinator Layout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-coordinatorlayout, buttonclick

I have place a coordinater layout inside a relative layout. The coordinator layout consists of two button. I designed the usual onclick function but the button does not seem to be clicked.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.shaby.payshare.WorkPageOneFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/add1"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:text="ADDBene"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/add2"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:text="AddItem"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Java File part as

```
buttonAddB= (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add1);


        buttonAddB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
```

The question is 1) Am I doing the correct thing? 2) If yes then why is the button not working?
Help.

Comment: Please post a **complete** code example. This means you must have a class and a method just like in the actual code you are compiling. This does **not** mean to post your entire code. You just need to give the surrounding class and method for the code you have shown here. I assume this code is from `onCreate()`, but you need to show that for me to be sure. You should also include the `super()` and `setContentView()` lines.

Comment: In addition, please explain what "not working" means. What happens when yhou click the button? What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Other codes was irrelevent to this, thats why i dint posted. And this java code is in **onCreateView(...)** . For simplicity I have edited the post and believe me other part was not needed here.

Comment: and by not working I mean the view is been create successfully but when I click the button no toast is generated and no button press effect was shown by button.

Comment: Please reread my first comment and edit your question as requested. I appreciate that you are trying to keep your code at a minimal amount. However, you have taken it a bit too far and left out code that is needed to help you. For example, your question does not say that you are using a fragment. This is an important detail and can easily be shown in your code with something like `class MyFragment extends Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1) Check to see what `view` is in `buttonAddB= (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add1)` and that it refers to what you think it refers to;

2) You don't say what happens when things fail, so I am guessing it's a NPE. Try changing `Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()` to `Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()` to see if that works. `getContext()` may be returning null.

If these don't fix it, post a little more information about the failure.

Comment: Nothing as a error is shown. Its just view appears perfectly as I thought of but the button press was having no effect.

Comment: I doubt even if the button press event happened or not when I pressed.

Comment: I have given complete xml layout.

Comment: Yes I tried it. But I tried it in separate piece of code because I changed the layout much before. And in separate code it was not an issue there, everything was smooth running. I dont know what had happened then probably my dynamic layout might be overlapping the button. Anyways thanx for help.